# Renaming a Web API controller has broken POST routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I've got a Web API controller supplying data to an Angular SPA which I decided to rename, using VS 2015's rename functionality to update all my references. As a result, I can't POST to it any more (GET still works though), I keep getting the following error on the client:

```
"A route named 'api/Trainees' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name"
```

This controller had previously worked fine using the default routing - nothing in `RouteConfig.cs` and no attribute routing which makes it all the stranger. I assumed ASP.NET worked out the default routing just from the controller and method names, or does it cache routing information anywhere?

My controller looks like this:

```
public class TraineesController : ApiController
{
    private UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

    // GET: api/Trainees
    public IEnumerable<Trainee> Get()
    {
        return this.repo.GetUsers();
    }

    // GET: api/Trainees/5
    public Trainee Get(string email)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return this.repo.GetUser(email);
        }

        throw new ArgumentNullException("email");
    }

    // POST: api/Trainees
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Trainee value)
    {
        try
        {
            this.repo.AddUser(value);
            return CreatedAtRoute("api/Trainees", value.Email, value);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
    }

    // PUT: api/Trainees/5
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]Trainee value)
    {
        try
        {
            this.repo.UpdateUser(value);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    // DELETE: api/Trainees/5
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            this.repo.RemoveUser(email);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the failing request (generated by Angular $resource):

```
Request:    POST /api/Trainees HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:   application/json;charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer:    http://localhost:11423/
Accept-Language:    en-GB
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host:   localhost:11423
Content-Length: 64
DNT:    1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
```

Body:

```
{"Email":"tony@starkindustries.com","DisplayName":"Tony Stark"}
```

Comment: Can you show the full uri request?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you try 3 things because i don´t see nothing wrong. The first is to call the api with "api/trainess" lower case T the second add on the route config `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` just to see the third is to try route prefix on the controller `[RoutePrefix("api/trainees")] public class TraineesController : ApiController`  and  `[HttpPost,Route("")] public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Trainee value)`. Try every one apart not at same time

Comment: None of that worked I'm afraid! MapHttpAttributeRoutes() was already set, so I'm even more puzzled why explicitly specifying the route attributes didn't work.

Comment: Can you tell what is inside of Global.asax.cs ? Sory to that I´m asking to many question but I´m trying to help.

Comment: I've worked it out. The route it can't find is the one in `CreatedAtRoute("api/Trainees", value.Email, value);` I'm not sure why I can't find it, but I've replaced `CreatedAtRoute` with `Created` and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Good to know that you are able to unblock yourself. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! The whole thing is a bit strange, but at least I've got a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit late, but this happens because you're trying to pass a `route template` as the first parameter of `CreatedAtRoute`

```
return CreatedAtRoute("api/Trainees", value.Email, value);
```

You need to pass a route name. You can name your route using **`RouteAttribute`**

```
[Route("api/Trainees", Name="TraineesRoute")]`
```